# Visual Studio 2015 Release Candiate - Broken intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I recently downloaded the release canditate of Visual Studio 2015 and created a new vNext ASP.NET MVC website (from the template). Everything builds fine, however IntelliSense is unable to resolve anything.

In earlier versions (beta etc.), I had this problem too but it was mostly because the assemblies really weren't there (broken nuget sources, project.json with outdated configuration). But this time, everything is *as provided*.

Anyone else facing this issue? Is there a way to resolve it?

[image: intellibooh]

Comment: Does it happen immediately after loading a project or only after some coding? I face this problem in 2013 and earlier as well, but a VS restart helps with that all the time. From what I've noticed this happens when I either Esc the autocomplete box all the time, or make too many typos so it fails to find out what I meant.

Comment: @Balázs Yes. It happens immediately after loading the project. The project initializes and (of course) doesn't find any references. Then those are restored automatically by nuget. But I assume by the time the references are restored, IntelliSense already made a boo boo. Restarting the project doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Did you check Windows Event Viewer? Are there any recent errors that could be related?